# Print text of anchor link using BeautifulSoap library | python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am web-scraping a website named pakwheels.com. I want to get year of a car.

```
https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/suzuki-cultus-2018-for-sale-in-lahore-6596122
```

The year can be get from this part of HTML.

[image]

I want to print the text of the anchor link using BeautifulSoap library. Tried different variations of the code but had no success, please help.

my output should be: 2018

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: *"Tried different variations of the code"* - you should really include at least one of those variations and whatever output/s you *did* get

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the `a` tag using `select_one` with the [css selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) `'span.engine-icon.year + p > a'` and then get the text using `get_text`.

For example, if you were looking at a car from [pakwheels.com](https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/suzuki-cultus-2018-for-sale-in-lahore-6596122) [the html in your screenshot looks like just like this site's], then

```py
r = requests.get('https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/suzuki-cultus-2018-for-sale-in-lahore-6596122')
if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    hlYear = soup.select_one('span.engine-icon.year + p > a')
    if hlYear is not None:
        print(hlYear.get_text(strip=True))
```

would print `2018`.